# Convert Python list comprehension to for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and trying to learn python, can anyone help me to convert the python list comprehension to for loop.

> ```
> words = ["yo", "act", "flop", "tac"]
> sortedWords = ["".join(sorted(w)) for w in words]
> print(sortedWords)
> ```

> ```
> # Above will output : 
> ['oy', 'act', 'flop', 'act']
> ```

now I want to convert Into for loop, I'm trying the below code but not getting the above output.

> ```
> for w in words:
>     finalword = []
>     finalword.append("".join(sorted(w)))
>     print(finalword)
> ```

getting below output :

> ```
> ['oy']
> ['act']
> ['flop']
> ['act']
> ```
>
> Desired output : `['oy', 'act', 'flop', 'act']`

Please help not sure how to do that.

Comment: Put `finalword = []` *before* the loop, not inside the loop.

Comment: @deceze its giving below result :                                                                               ['oy']
['oy', 'act']
['oy', 'act', 'flop']
['oy', 'act', 'flop', 'act']

Comment: That's what you want, right? You might just want to move the `print` to *after* the loop as well…

Comment: @deceze oh ok thanks got it, but can u tell me why we have to put finalword=[] before for loop ? not understand the logic. appreciate your help

Comment: Think it through. It's imperative code. It does things step by step. If you set `finalword` to an empty list *for every step in the loop*, well, then you can't end up with a list that contains more than one loop's worth of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
words = ["yo", "act", "flop", "tac"]
finalWord =[] 
for w in words:
    finalWord.append(''.join(sorted(w)))
print(finalWord)
```

This works.

Output is:
`['oy', 'act', 'flop', 'act']`